# I have the day of the year. How to obtain the date in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, date, unix

example Day of the year: 305

how to get the date in dd-mm-yyyy format

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU `date` (as implied by the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag) you can do

```
date -d "1/1 + 304 days" +%d-%m-%Y
```